# Using roomdatabase query for search between products

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

before get to my issue let me tell you how my app works.

I have A little Grocery App and fetch data from an api with retrofit and after that save it to Roomdatabase.

For better Ui experiment I need to implement searchview with an edittext on my main screen .

So , I decide to code a query in my dao and get all data by title filter .

But the problem is that , when I fill the edittext and click on button to get the product that I filter it nothing happened and doesn't any search .

Well , I guess maybe my problem would be with my code that I implement in repository and viewmodel to insert data to roomdatabase . if not , what's wrong with my code ?

I will be appreciated if you look at my code .

and here is my code :

This is room table :

```
@Entity(tableName = "newTable")
data class RoomEntity(
    
    @PrimaryKey
        (autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int? ,
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val image: String

)
```

Dao :

```
@Dao
interface RoomDaoQuery {



    @Query("SELECT * FROM newTable")
    fun getAllProduct () : LiveData<List<RoomEntity>>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertDataToDatabase(model : List<RoomEntity>)


    @Query("SELECT * FROM newTable WHERE title LIKE '%' || :search || '%'")
    fun searchByName(search: String): List<RoomEntity>

}
```

Repository :

```
class Repository(private val database: DatabaseRoom) {


    fun getAllProduct() = database.GetDao.getAllProduct()


    private fun retrofit(): ApiRetrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.43.106/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .build()
            .create(ApiRetrofit::class.java)

    }


    suspend fun fettchAllDat(): List<RoomEntity> {
        return retrofit().getProduct()

    }

    suspend fun insertToDatabase(model : List<RoomEntity>) {

        database.GetDao.insertDataToDatabase(fettchAllDat())


    }

    // this is for local search

     fun searchWithName (title : String) : List<RoomEntity> {


        return database.GetDao.searchByName(title)


    }


}
```

Viewmodel:

```
class ViewmodelRoom(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val product = MutableLiveData<List<RoomEntity>>()
    private val repository = Repository(DatabaseRoom.getInstance(application))
    private var viewModelJob = SupervisorJob()
    private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Default)



 fun getAllProduct() = repository.getAllProduct()



    fun setup() {

        viewModelScope.launch{
            product.postValue(repository.fettchAllDat())
            insertall()


        }

    }

    fun insertall() {


        viewModelScope.launch {

            repository.insertToDatabase(repository.fettchAllDat())

        }
    }

    fun searchByTitle(title : String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{


        repository.searchWithName(title)


    }

}
```

and MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    val viewModel: ViewmodelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewmodelRoom::class.java)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext)
        val search: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.searchview)
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)


        search.setOnClickListener {


         viewModel.searchByTitle(editText.text.toString())
            editText.text.clear()


        }



        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                viewModel.searchByTitle(editText.text.toString())

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
        })



        if (isNetworkAvaliable(applicationContext)) {

            viewModel.setup()
            viewModel.product.observe(this, Observer {

                recyclerView.apply {

                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
                    adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(it, this@MainActivity)

                }

            })

        } else {


            viewModel.getAllProduct().observe(this, Observer { list ->
                recyclerView.apply {
                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
                    adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(list, this@MainActivity)

                }
            })
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

finally I get to a proper result .
I put my code here , I hope maybe useful for someone .

the Dao :

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM newTable WHERE title LIKE :name")
    fun search (name : String) :LiveData<List<RoomEntity>>
```

Repository :

```
    fun search(name : String): LiveData<List<RoomEntity>>{

        return database.GetDao.search(name)
    }
```

```
fun search(name : String) : LiveData<List<RoomEntity>> {

    return repository.search(name)

}
```

```
MainActivity :
```

```
    val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext)
    val search: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.searchview)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)


    search.setOnClickListener {

// this is an extention function that observe data
        searchProduct(editText.text.toString())


    }

   editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            searchProduct(editText.text.toString())
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {


        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
    })

private fun searchProduct(title : String) {


    var searchText = title
    searchText = "%$title%"

        viewModel.search(searchText).observe(this@MainActivity , Observer {

        d("main" , "$it")

            recyclerView.apply {
                layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
                adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(it, this@MainActivity)


                }
        })

    }
```